# The ng-model does not change and therefore $error.required does not work when the input value is changed by a date picker

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code (after eliminating layout stuff):

```
<span ng-show="myForm.date.$error.required">*</span>
<input type="text" ng-model="date" name="date" required>
<img id="date_btn" src="../../etc/img/cal.png">
```

When I click on the date picker and select the date, the date is written inside the input but it seems that the ng-model does not change (The * does not disappear and also the $scope.$watch() does not fire for date).
Thanks in Advance

Comment: change ng-model="date" to ng-model="date1" and see if works, may be date is reserved keyword

Comment: did you wrap your input with `form` with `name="myForm"`?

Comment: What datepicker do you use? If you want the native you can do `<input type="date" />`

Comment: Try this myForm.input.$error.required

Comment: Thank you all but the problem is still there.

Comment: What datepicker do you use? If you want the native you can do `<input type="date" />`

Comment: @devqon, It is a jalali date picker (http://farhadi.ir/projects/jalalijscalendar/)

Comment: And do you use it in a directive? Or how do you initialize your datepicker? Probably the * does disappear when you type something manually?

Comment: @devqon, I don't use it in a directive. There is a setup function which is called inside the controller. Exactly, it does disappear when something is typed manually.

Comment: The datepicker you're using doesn't know of angular, so it acts outside of the digest cycle. Therefore angular doesn't know when the value is changed if you select it.

Comment: @devqon, Is there a way to make angular aware of the change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151493/discussion-between-devqon-and-mohammad).